# How can I run a loop with a tensor as its range? (in tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I want to have a for loop that the number of its iterations is depend on a tensor value. For example:

```
for i in tf.range(input_placeholder[1,1]):
  # do something
```

However I get the following error:

**"TypeError: 'Tensor' object is not iterable"**

What should I do?

Answer (score 36):

To do this you will need to use the tensorflow while loop ([`tf.while_loop`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop)) as follows:

```
i = tf.constant(0)
while_condition = lambda i: tf.less(i, input_placeholder[1, 1])
def body(i):
    # do something here which you want to do in your loop
    # increment i
    return [tf.add(i, 1)]

# do the loop:
r = tf.while_loop(while_condition, body, [i])
```

Comment: what about when i have a variable in the loop ? I get an reference error
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47760429/tensorflow-local-variable-lstm-state-referenced-before-assignment

Comment: This seems to work, but seems to directly contradict the Tensorflow advice: "For correct programs, while_loop should return the same result for any parallel_iterations > 0." It seems like this may set up a race condition leading to the loop being evaluated anywhere between "n" and "n*parallel_iterations" times

Answer (score -8):

The type of the return value of TensorFlow Python API functions, including `tf.range` is a [`Tensor`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py#L114). A `Tensor` is a symbolic handle to node in a graph that represents computation. You perform the actual computation by calling the `eval` method on a `Tensor`, or by passing the object to `run` method of a `Session`. In your case, perhaps what you intended to do was simply iterate over `numpy`'s `range`.

```
for in in np.range(...):
  # do something
```

Comment: No, this is not what I am looking for. I want a loop to operate k times while k is determined based on the input. Input is a tensor placeholder.

Comment: In fact, I have two inputs. First one is a matrix, and the second one is how many times a specific operation should be done on that.

Comment: When you're writing a tensorflow op, having numpy calls, prevents the op from running on the GPU, so it's important for the op to have only GPU compliant tensorflow ops in it.