# Canonical Tensorflow "for loop"

Tags: tensorflow

What is the canonical way of running a Tensorflow "for loop"?

Specifically, suppose we have some `body` function which does NOT depend on the loop iteration, but must be run `n` times.

One might think that a good method might be to run this inside of a [`tf.while_loop`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops/control_flow_operations#while_loop) like this:

```
def body(x):
    return ...

def while_body(i,x):
    return i+1, body(x) 

i, x = tf.while_loop(lambda i: tf.less(i, n), while_body, [tf.constant(0),x])
```

In fact, that is precisely what the highest rated answer in this question suggests:

[How can I run a loop with a tensor as its range? (in tensorflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35330117/how-can-i-run-a-loop-with-a-tensor-as-its-range-in-tensorflow)

However, the [`tf.while_loop` docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops/control_flow_operations#while_loop) specifically say

> For correct programs, while_loop should return the same result for any parallel_iterations > 0.

If you put a counter in the body, then it seems that that condition is violated. So it seems that there must be a different way of setting up a "for loop".

Furthermore, even if there is no explicit error, doing so seems like it will create a dependency between iterations meaning that I do not think they will run in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, it seems that the `tf.while_loop` idiom used above is quite common. Alternatively, one can use `tf.scan`:

```
def body( x ):
    return ...

def scan_body( previous_output, iteration ):
    return body( ... )

x = tf.scan( scan_body, tf.range(n), initializer = [x] )
```

although I have no idea if one is preferable from a performance point of view. Note in the above that we have to wrap the `body` function to accept the previous output.